# ArrayList overwriting only and not adding data

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

i want to create a 'Add Account' Application. I've created a ArrayList and store it to a textfile, however, it only write one set of data to textfile.

Ex: Account Name: Joe
    Account Number: 10
When i press, 'Save' button, it's now saved in the textfile, but when i create a new accont, for example: Account Name: Ryan, Account Number: 20, the first account that i've create has been overwrited. Could you please advise what is wrong on my code?

```
public class JFrameNewAccount extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    private void btnSaveAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(rad_savings);
        bg.add(rad_checking);
        al.add(txt_accountnumber.getText());
        al.add((txt_accountname.getText()));
        if (rad_savings.isSelected()) {
            al.add(rad_savings.getText());
        } else {
            al.add(rad_checking.getText());
            al.add(txt_initialbalance.getText());
            if (rad_savings.isSelected()) {
                al.add(txt_interestrate.getText());
            } else {
                al.add(txt_overdraft.getText());
            }
            String fileName = "bank.txt";
            FileWriter file = null;
            try {
                file = new FileWriter(fileName);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
                for (String str : al) {
                    pw.println(str);
                }
                pw.flush();
                System.out.println("Write successful...");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("File not found....");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JFrameNewAccount.class.getName()).log(
                        Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    file.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JFrameNewAccount.class.getName()).log(
                            Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(this, "Your accont has been created!");
            txt_accountname.setText("");
            txt_accountnumber.setText("");
            txt_initialbalance.setText("");
            txt_overdraft.setText("");
            txt_interestrate.setText("");
            bg.clearSelection();
            txt_accountnumber.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you declared the `List` ? To append to an existing file , you need to have `file = new FileWriter(fileName.true);` .

Comment: Did you try debugging the program? Make sure the data is **appended** to the file contents. I'd also recommend separating responsibilities so you can have a more maintainable code in which problems are also easier to spot. **[This](http://www.e-reading-lib.org/bookreader.php/134601/Clean_Code_-_A_Handbook_of_Agile_Software_Craftsmanship.pdf)** book can help a lot in improving code quality.

Comment: Just a general note on your code: The way you close the Writer in the `finally` block might cause your programm to crash with a `NullPointerException` if the `FileWriter` constructor throws and `IOException`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems your FileWriter overwrites the output file every time. Try `file = new FileWriter(fileName, true)`, which puts it into an append mode and adds data to the output file instead.

Answer (score 2):

To append to an existing file , you need to use the overloaded constructor of [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,boolean%29) , which takes two arguments . The signature is :

```
public FileWriter(String fileName,
      boolean append)
       throws IOException
```

*Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.*

You can use that as :

```
file = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
```

Comment: file = new FileWriter(fileName, true);

Comment: file = new FileWriter(fileName, true);

This seems work and what Expected output i got. Thanks mate!
Question, how do i add a new set of data in a new line in a textfile? it seems appending data is only one straight line.

Comment: Use the newline `"\n"` character , I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry but, could you please advise on what part of my code should i insert that?

Comment: `pw.println(str+"\n");`

Comment: it print new line for every text, is it possbile for this example?
I mean, for every account, it will new line for the new aacount.
Account number: 101
Account name: Joe\n

Account number: 102
Account name: Ryan

Comment: Add "\n" after for loop.

Comment: `try {
            file = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            for(String str: al) {
                pw.println(str);
            }
            pw.println("\n");`

I've add this, it duplicate the 1st set of data.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about doing this. Overwriting the FileWriter seems like a decent option but you will still need to perform the following:

1. Load the ArrayList saved in the text file.
2. Add the new data to the ArrayList (Using .add())
3. Save the ArrayList to the file (overwriting whatever is there before).

If you append to the text file, you would have saved TWO ArrayLists to the text file which (I believe) is not the intended outcome.